# How to symbolicate iOS system framework such as UIKit?

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

I am working on a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on iOS:

I register a handler:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myHandler);
```

I receive a callback on App Crash,

```
void myHandler(NSException * exception)
{
    //i can get stack symbols from
    //exception.callStackSymbols;
}
```

The following is the stacks i get:

```
6   UIKit   0x000000018a6622c8  <redacted> + 612 
7   UIKit   0x000000018a678b88  <redacted> + 592 
8   UIKit   0x000000018a678814  <redacted> + 700 
9   UIKit   0x000000018a671d50  <redacted> + 684 
10  UIKit   0x000000018a644f74  <redacted> + 264
```

I want to symbolicate the 'redacted' part.

What i tried:

- System frameworks and it's dsyms file:

```
/Users/my_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/8.4.1\ \(12H321\)/symbols/system/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

- Using xcrun atos tool to symbolicate this line:

```
6   UIKit   0x000000018a6622c8  <redacted> + 612

xcrun atos -arch arm64 -o /Users/my_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/8.4.1\ \(12H321\)/symbols/system/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit -l 0x18a662064 0x000000018a6622c8
```

I can't find the right output from this command. What did I miss?
My question goes: How to symbolicate the system framework such as `UIKit`?